# GDB inferior quit

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I was trying a program with GDB, I did a 'break x' and then was running step by step. So when I want to quit, I would say 'quit', it would return an 'inferior process will be killed warning message'. What happens if I do 'Y'. Because I want to somehow come out of the process. And what would happen If I attach a running process and quit. Will it be detached or the running process will be exited? Different sources give different ideas. Please advise.

Also, when I try to run a program it says, and I am running the standard program from peter's tutorial. It gives this error when I do an step to line 16.

```
 _IO_puts (str=0x40075e "In display():") at ioputs.c:35
 35 ioputs.c: No such file or directory.
     in ioputs.c
```

Program

```
  14 void display(int z, int *zptr) {
  15        printf("In display():\n");
  **16       printf("   z is %d and is stored at %p.\n", z, &z);**
  17       printf("   zptr points to %p which holds %d.\n", zptr, *zptr);
  18   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the process in the debugger and quit the debugger, the running program is killed (just as you would with SIGKILL). To end the program normally, say `continue` (possibly with a number large of ignores) until the program is done.

If you *attach* the debugger to a running program and exit the debugger, the debugger will just detach and the program continues running, unless you kill it beforehand.

Comment: That solved the problem, Thanks. But I keep getting the ioputs.c:no such file directory only if I use 'step'. Else the program exits normally. I guess when the program have a printf, it traces back to the library function and etc. But thats not how it is mentioned in the tutorial.Just makes me wonder, what might be the problem. May be a different version of gcc or gdb?

Comment: You just don't have the source code for the C library. Don't worry about it. Just step *over* the C library functions (`n` rather than `s`).

Comment: "To end the program normally, say continue (possibly with a number large of ignores)" -- an easier way is to `detach` and `quit` instead.

Comment: @EmployedRussian: That's true, but when you detatch, the program is no longer in the debugger. It's certainly an option, but for example if there's a chance that your program crashes during shutdown, you might like to end it *in* the debugger. Anyway, thanks for the note.

Comment: If you're on debian you can install the source file with ''apt-get source glibc''